# im reading the excel file in python-pandas using the below code in centos but im getting error

Tags: python, excel, pandas, centos7

**pyxel.py**

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelFile
data = pd.read_excel("path/dat.xlsx",sheet_name="sheet")
print(data)
```

In the above code, I'm just reading the excel file and printing the data. 
I'm getting the below error as in the image
[image]

Can anyone help me with the mistake I made?

Comment: I think your import statement is wrong. For example just use `import pandas as pd`

Comment: even after im getting the same error.

Comment: The error is at ```import pandas as pd``` This means that there is problem in installation of pandas. Uninstall and reinstall pandas and see if this is resolved

Comment: It worked. Thanks Dave and Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

try this command, use 2 forward slashes instead of one or u can try with an r'

option1

```
data = pd.read_excel("path//dat.xlsx",sheet_name="sheet")
```

option2

```
data = pd.read_excel(r'path/dat.xlsx',sheet_name="sheet")
```

Hope this works!!